# Python: convert usual text to executable machine code

Tags: python, dsl

I need to solve the task, connecting with creating of `DSL`.
First, what should I do to translate text to machine code.
For example:

> text: 'If salary more than 5000 do op1'

should be translated to..

```
if salary > 5000:
    op1
```

Is any way to do it? Maybe it other langs

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a compiler, Most popular compiler constructors are Yacc & Flex using BISON GNU.

Yacc:
[Yacc wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) & [BISON GNU Docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)

But before going through that, you need to know about context free grammars.

[Context Free Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)

you can parse a language only if it is deterministic as in there is a single rule to parse that sentence